# Where should javascript files and stylesheets be added to a Rails project?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, stylesheet

I'm unclear about where javascript files and stylesheets should be added to a Rails project. Perhaps they should be added to `public/javascripts` and `public/stylesheets` respectively. Then they're copied to `app/assets`? Or perhaps it's the other way around.

I've experimented with `<%= stylesheet_link_tag :all %>` and `:default` and just explicitly naming my stylesheets but I'm still confused.

**Where should javascript files and stylesheets be added to a Rails project?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the other way around. You add stylesheets and javascripts to their respectable folders in assets.

You then use:

```
= stylesheet_link_tag     "application"
= javascript_include_tag  "application"
```

Check the guide for details http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

Answer (score 2):

In a Rails 3.1 application, where the asset pipeline is enabled, you want to place your script/stylesheet assets in `app/assets`. Rails will automagically find them via Sprockets and serve them up minimized and contaminated (in production).